# Do transactions made using REST API show when using Classic API?

Tags: paypal

I know that transactions made via Classic API will not return when using the REST API. But what about vice versa? Can I pull all transactions if using the Classic API?

Answer (score 1):

The REST API uses a different set of IDs for its data model which are not analogous/compatible with the IDs used by the classic APIs.

So at the moment this is not possible.